# Creating a post link with Elixir and Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to hit the create action in my questions controller from a link, but I can't seem to get it working.

#### LINK:

```
<%= link "Create question", to: question_path(@conn, :create), method: :post %>
```

#### CONTROLLER:

```
defmodule StatcastersWeb.QuestionController do
  import Ecto.Query
  use StatcastersWeb, :controller
  alias Statcasters.{League, Repo, UsersLeagues, SportRadar}
  require IEx

  def create(conn, _params) do
    IEx.pry
    games = Nba.get_todays_games
  end
end
```

Do you know how I can do this with Elixir and Phoenix?

#### ROUTER:

```
resources "/questions", QuestionController
get "/build_question", QuestionController, :build_question
```

#### ERROR:

```
lib/statcasters_web/templates/page/index.html.eex:8: undefined function question_path/2
```

Comment: Show the router code.

Comment: Okay, one moment.

Comment: Running `mix phx.routes` will tell you all the routes in your application. Maybe check that?

Comment: Can you post the complete router code? Are those lines nested in another `resources` call?